# Google Wallet for digital goods stopped working

Tags: postback, android-pay

We are trying to integrate Google Wallet for digital goods with or php app and 2 days ago, on 15 November we've managed to get it working. However, when checking again the next day and even today, although the code remained the same, we didn't change a letter in it, it is still not working, giving us this error:

Uh oh. There was a problem.

We couldn't complete your purchase because of a technical issue.

Details of the problem below: Unfortunately, we could not confirm your purchase with the merchant's server. Your order has been canceled. Please contact the merchant if this problem continues.

The code we're using is this:

```
    $response = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : file_get_contents("php://input");

    $response = substr_replace($response, "", 0, 4);   //remove "

    $response = JWT::decode($response, $sellerSecretKey);

    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

and like I said it worked fine two days ago and I have the feeling it's working now also, because in our log file we get printed this response

stdClass Object
(
    [iss] => Google
    [request] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product 1.
            [description] => You are purchasing a total of 1 products from our Store. Thank you.
            [price] => 9.99
            [currencyCode] => USD
            [sellerData] => client name,email address
        )

```
[response] => stdClass Object
    (
        [orderId] => GWDG_S.c7a66f5b-4674-43f0-be16-2b72f69a7445
    )

[typ] => google/payments/inapp/item/v1/postback/buy
[aud] => 03083876603093172875
[iat] => 1384689627
[exp] => 1384689647
```

)

The postback url is correctly specified and we are using sandbox to do the tests.

Is this a problem from Google? Are they working on the software or something and this is what's causing the problem? Or are we doing something wrong here?.

Any help would be much apreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meant to comment but it won't fit...

That error points to something in your [Postback handler](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/postback). I just tried sandbox and things seem fine.

I'm **not** a php dev so this maybe inaccurate - are you responding to Postback with the `orderId`? Again, this is only based on my read of the code above (I *think* I only see http 200?)

The only other thing I can think of is that the lag for you to respond is more than 10 seconds(?) - which <strike>could explain why</strike> could be another reason <strike>you have logged data, but</strike> Google <strike>still</strike> cancelled it.

**<strike>Strike through</strike> text: you'd get data to log because Google will send you the data, it's whether or not you respond properly that matters*

> Once you decode the JWT with your Seller Secret, you can make sure that the cake purchase is OK and record it. **Within 10 seconds** of receiving the postback, your server must send a 200 OK response where **the only content is the value of the "orderId" field**. If it doesn't, Google cancels the transaction.
>
> REF: https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/postback#responding

Hth.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to look into this even though you are not a php developer. You're answer helped me a lot and got me to the right way. I'm not a php dev my self either and I'm pretty new to developing but the proble is I didn't read the documentation carefully enough. You were right, it was missing the order ID, all I had to do is add another line to echo the order id (echo $response->response;) and it did the job. Thank you very much again. Cheers.